# Working with autorotation and UINavigationBar images

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimage, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a navigation bar that uses a custom image for the background. Along with some images for buttons UIBarButtonItems.

When the device is rotated the navigation bar height is obviously changed to 32px instead of 44px.

Is it best practice to then make another image to be used for the navigation bar background or create stretchable images instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would create two stretchable images one for retina an one for default devices, it's is best practice to use stretchable images instead of full length images because you decrease the app size and there will be no problems if the device screen size is changed (if the stretchable image is seted properly)